# Neo4j: 3.0.0 Memory allocation

Tags: neo4j

3.0.0 M05 beta on Windows 7 64 bit

I'm trying to load a CSV using PERIODIC COMMIT, and I'm getting a *Java heap space* error.

I've tried setting -Xmx512M or -Xmx3G and watching windows task manager, the memory allocation stays ~300M.

What setting do I need to change to allocate more memory to the server so I can get the db to use more memory?

(As a note, a stock out-of-the box 2.3.2 installation processes all these CSV files no problem...)

**Update 1:**

-Xmx512M and -Xmx3G were set in the "neo4j-community.vmoptions" file

**Update 2: I found a log file:**

neo4j.log:

```
2016-03-21 17:50:49.293-0400 INFO  [o.n.s.d.LifecycleManagingDatabase] Starting...
2016-03-21 17:51:00.449-0400 INFO  [o.n.s.d.LifecycleManagingDatabase] Started.
Mar 21, 2016 5:51:01 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
Mar 21, 2016 5:51:02 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
Mar 21, 2016 5:51:02 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
2016-03-21 17:51:03.099-0400 INFO  [o.n.s.CommunityNeoServer] Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
Exception in thread "neo4j.PauseMonitor" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

**Update 3:**

There's no "neo4j-wrapper.conf" on my system nor is NEO4J_HOME set. Setting this env var and creating  neo4j-wrapper.conf doesn't change the behavior - the server maxes out around 300M and dies with a heap error when I try to do the load.

Answer (score 1):

By default the Java heap size should be dynamically calculated based on system resources, but it sounds like that is not working properly here. Are you using milestone 5 version of 3.0 (most recent milestone release)?

In `conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf` config file there are two options for specifying initial and maximum memory for JVM heap size:

```
wrapper.java.initmemory
wrapper.java.maxmemory
```

How were you specifying `-Xmx512M` and `-Xmx3G`? In `conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf` using `wrapper.java.additional`?

Comment: I'm using 3.0.0 M05, stock install. I can't find this ".conf" file in either the application, db, or "C:\Users" directory. Where should it be?

Comment: There is a "neo4j.conf" file under "C:\Users\tdk\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Community Edition" - is this the same as the "wrapper" conf file?

Comment: It should be in the `conf` directory of the Neo4j install. See http://neo4j.com/docs/3.0.0-M05/server-performance.html

Comment: The docs say neo4j-wrapper.conf is supposed to be in the conf directory of NEO4J_HOME. NEO4J_HOME is not set on my system, and there's no "conf" directory in any of the usual locations. I have 2.2.8 and 2.3.2 installed if it makes a difference.

Comment: I've tried creating a system env variable for NEO4J_HOME and pointing it at the "community edition" folder, and creating a neo4j-wrapper.conf file to no avail. The session maxes out at ~300M then dies with a "heap error"

Comment: Which installation method? Zip or exe? The root dir of the extracted zip should be considered `NEO4J_HOME`

Comment: I was using the exe. I'm working with Dave now and have gone to the .zip version.